# Unable to get SYN-ACK for manually created TCP SYN packet

Tags: tcp, localhost

I was trying to send a SYN packet to a TCP server opened at `localhost:8083` (via ncat), using Linux RAW sockets, but I was not getting any SYN-ACK reply from it.

I thought there was some issue with my implementation regarding checksum, so I decided to use libtins library. Again, I was not receiving any SYN-ACK reply from ncat TCP server. Can someone help in figuring out how to get the SYN-ACK reply?

Here is the command which I used to run TCP server:

```
ncat -l 8083
```

Here is the C++ code using libtins library:

```
#include <tins/tins.h>

using namespace Tins;

int main()
{
    NetworkInterface iface = NetworkInterface::default_interface();
    PacketSender sender;
    TCP tcp_packet;

    // Set TCP header fields
    tcp_packet.sport(40512); // Source port
    tcp_packet.dport(8083);   // Destination port
    tcp_packet.seq(52366);   // Sequence number
    tcp_packet.flags(TCP::SYN); // Flags (e.g., SYN, ACK)
    tcp_packet.window(65535); // Window size
    tcp_packet.mss(1460);
    tcp_packet.sack_permitted();
    tcp_packet.timestamp(0, 0);
    tcp_packet.add_option(TCP::NOP);
    tcp_packet.winscale(7);

    EthernetII pkt = EthernetII() / IP("172.27.144.151", "172.27.144.151") / tcp_packet;
    sender.send(pkt, iface);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the image from packet capture: [Packet Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgwLv.png).

Notice that I tried sending request from ncat client after some time and I got the SYN-ACK reply from server, but not for the packet generated from libtins.

(I am sending packet to `172.27.144.151` instead of `127.0.0.1` (in code). Sending packets to `127.0.0.1` was also not working).

I am stuck on this problem for almost a week, and tried everything that I can think of, but I am not getting any result at all.